# Fatal Error: Smarty error: the $compile_dir 'template_c' does not exist

Tags: php, apache, smarty

**Fatal error: Smarty error: the $compile_dir '/templates_c' does not exist, or is not a directory.**

```
   8 drwxrwxrwx@   32 _www  staff    2048 Aug 21  2014 templates
 104 drwxrwxrwx@  556 _www  staff   49152 Mar 18 14:52 templates_c
```

I have tried everything that I can search to fix this error.
*Anyone have any ideas why I cannot get this to work?*

Comment: Please tell - do you use `$smarty->setCompileDir(...)` function ? If not, check if `templates_c` folder exists in main directory of your web application - if it does not, please create it and try again. Hope it helps some way?

Comment: #--- Smarty Settings ---
smarty:

template_dir:templates
  
compile_dir:templates_c

functions_dir:include/smarty_plugins/functions

modifiers_dir:include/smarty_plugins/modifiers

Comment: The template_c exists in main directory of web application

Comment: This app was working fine before the database crashed.  I had to reinstall postgresql82, which reinstalled php, et all

Comment: Sadly nothing more comes to my mind for now - if I come up with something hopefully useful, I'll try to write ASAP. I hope you get the help needed.

Comment: This is what I did to make it work.  The permissions on templates_c and templates were set at 777, I changed it to 755.  I also changes the permissions for the smarty and smarty plugins folder to 755 recursively.

Comment: Congratulations ! :)